# Verifying an identity of an equation for Black Scholes formula

Tags: black-scholes, calculation

I just started working on the Black Scholes formula with help of the book Financial option valuation by Higham. Apparently you are possible to derive the following function:

$\log(\frac{SN'(d_1)}{e^{-r(T-t)}EN'(d_2)}) = 0$

From the Black scholes formula:
$C(S,t)=SN(d_1)-Ee^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)$

I've been puzzling arround but I'm stuck. This is where I came so far, do you know where I'm going wrong?

$\log(\frac{SN'(d_1)}{e^{-r(T-t)}EN'(d_2)}) = \log(SN'(d_1))-\log(e^{-r(T-t)}EN'(d_2))=0$

Comment: $N'$ is the derivatve of the normal cdf - right? What if you plug in?

Comment: Yes, $N'$ is the derivative of a normal cdf. So you could rewrite that as $N'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$ But what do you mean with "plug in"?

Comment: Keep going with the substitution, you will see.

Comment: You plug-in $d1$ and $d2$ ...

Comment: Please don't cross post your question, see [this topic for guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/266114).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to fill in what Richard left for the second part:
\begin{align*}
\exp(-r(T-t))E\, N'(d_2) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-r(T-t))E\, \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}d_2^2\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-r(T-t))E\, \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\big(d_1-\sigma\sqrt{T-t}\,\big)^2\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-r(T-t))E\\
&\qquad\qquad \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} d_1^2 -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 (T-t) + d_1 \sigma\sqrt{T-t}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-r(T-t))E\\
&\qquad\qquad \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} d_1^2 +\ln(S/E) + r(T-t)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} S \, \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}d_1^2\right)\\
&= SN'(d_1).
\end{align*}
That is, 
\begin{align*}
\ln\frac{SN'(d_1)}{\exp(-r(T-t))E\, N'(d_2)} = 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: +1...better with d1 and d2...

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is
$$
S N'(d_1) = S  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp(-1/2 d_1^2) = \\
S \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}  \exp\left(- \frac12 \left(\log(S/E)+ (r + \frac12 \sigma^2(T-t)) \right)^2 / \sigma^2 (T-t) \right)  
$$
the denominator is:
$$
\exp(-r (T-t)) E N'(d_2) = \\  
E \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}  \exp\left(- \frac12 \left(\log(S/E)+(r- \frac12 \sigma^2(T-t)) \right)^2 / \sigma^2 (T-t) -r(T-t) \right).  
$$
Now what if we extend the square, match exp and log and if then nominator and denominator are equal we get the result.

EDIT: I did not finish the calculation. But the latex above is too much for a comment. Maybe you can do the calculation. It not that clear to see whether the claim is true...