# Result linked to Black-Scholes evaluation

Tags: black-scholes

Why does this

$$Se^{-D(T-t)}e^{-d_1^2/2} - Ee^{-r(T-t)}e^{-d_2^2/2}$$

equal to $0$? (Where $E$ is a strike)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that this question is similar to [Verifying an identity of an equation for Black Scholes formula](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21372/verifying-an-identity-of-an-equation-for-black-scholes-formula/21395#21395).

You need to use the fact that
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= \frac{\ln (S/E) + (r-D)(T-t) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}, \\
d_2 &= d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{T-t}.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
E e^{-r(T-t)} e^{-d_2^2/2} &=E e^{-r(T-t)} e^{-d_1^2/2 - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)+d_1 \sigma \sqrt{T-t}}\\
&=E e^{-r(T-t)} e^{-d_1^2/2 - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)+\ln (S/E) + (r-D)(T-t) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)}\\
&=Se^{-D(T-t)} e^{-d_1^2/2}.
\end{align*}