# Why is dividend discounted stock equal to cash discounted strike?

Tags: black-scholes, interest-rates, dividends

Doing some BS problem solving and came across this beauty:
$$S \cdot \text{exp}\Big(-D(T-t)\Big) \text{exp}\bigg(-\frac{d_{1}^{2}}{2}\bigg) = E \cdot \text{exp}\Big(-r(T-t)\Big) \text{exp}\bigg(-\frac{d_{2}^{2}}{2}\bigg)$$

$d_{2} = d_{1} - \sigma \sqrt{T-t}$ so it does not explain the difference.

Comment: There is a post on this site proving this identity (in a slightly different form) but I can't find it right now.

Comment: OK, here it is https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21372/verifying-an-identity-of-an-equation-for-black-scholes-formula/21395#21395 and https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21989/result-linked-to-black-scholes-evaluation/21991#21991