# Proof Black Scholes Theta

Tags: black-scholes, derivatives, greeks, call, black-scholes-pde

I saw the following proof of theta in a paper I read, and I thought it looked pretty neat. Unfortunately I don't understand the step that they do. 
This is what they do:

[image]

Now, I don't get how they go from $S_0 n(d_1)\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial t} - Xe^{-rt}n(d_2) \frac{\partial d_2}{\partial t}$ to $S_0 n(d1) \frac{\partial (d_1-d_2)}{\partial t}$. Could anyone explain to me why this is true?

Comment: Consider the relationship of $d_1$ and $d_2$ as well as the relationship of $n(d_1)$ and $n(d_2)$.

Comment: so $d_2 = d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{T}$, and consequently I thought $n(d_2) = n(d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{T})$. How can I use this to go further?

Comment: Would it help to write out the normal density function?

Comment: Yes, to write out the normal density function.

Comment: See also [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21372/verifying-an-identity-of-an-equation-for-black-scholes-formula/21395#21395).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a well known identity for the Black Scholes model: $S_0 n(d_1)-X e^{-rT} n(d_2) = 0$ ([proof](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21372/verifying-an-identity-of-an-equation-for-black-scholes-formula/21395#21395)).

Using this allows you to combine these two terms:

$$S_0 n(d_1)\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial t} - Xe^{-rT}n(d_2) \frac{\partial  d_2}{\partial t}$$

into

$$S_0 n(d1) (\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial d_2}{\partial t})$$

or

$$S_0 n(d1) \frac{\partial (d_1-d_2)}{\partial t}$$

Then we use the fact that $d_1-d_2=\sigma\sqrt{t}$

Answer (score 0):

Since Black Scholes Theta is for the Black–Scholes option pricing formula, the above step holds true.

For more info, refer page 3 and 4 of this pdf. http://moya.bus.miami.edu/~tsu/jef2008.pdf

Comment: This paper just repeats the equations above with no further explanation.